# Defining projection for FEWS rainfall data in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, usgs, coordinate-system, precipitation

This problem has been tackled here previously (see [Manually adding spatial reference information for FEWS rainfall data in ArcMap?](http://Manually%20adding%20spatial%20reference%20information%20for%20FEWS%20rainfall%20data%20in%20ArcMap?)) but i couldnt get a solution to my problem from the thread.

I am using the RFE data data for Kenya. After using Define Projection to Copy and Modify the Africa Albers as suggested (in ArcMap), the African rain does not map in the right place. The rain .bil data is a dot inside Africa in the ESRI world map (CNTRY92 shapefile).

However when i open the same .bil file in QGIS, it maps correctly.

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

I need to use the data in ArcMap for further analysis.

Comment: What is a link to where this has been tackled previously here?  What precisely happened when you tried tried to follow the advice offered there?

Comment: Here is a link to a similar case
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143960/how-to-manually-add-spatial-reference-information-for-fews-rainfall-data-in-arcm
For me the solution works in QGIS but not in ArcMap.

Comment: It may seem pedantic but one of the main differences between this focussed Q&A site, and any discussion forums you may also be using, is that we have Q&As rather than threads.  Adapting to focused Q&A is much easier when using the terminology adopted by the vast majority within the SE communities.

Comment: When you say "the African rain does not map in the right place" do you mean it is misaligned by a few hundred metres or what?  What is the coordinate system of your "African rain" and what is the coordinate system of the dataset that you are trying to align it with?

Comment: The rain .bil data is a dot inside Africa in the ESRI world map (CNTRY92 shapefile)